# Can't get rid of the white edging (artifact?) around the `border-top` line on a dark background

Tags: css, border

**Here is my code:**

```css
    html {
      background-color: rgba(47, 38, 31, 1.0);
    }
    
    .line {
      border-top: 30px solid #2274ca;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
      <body>
        <hr class="line">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Can I get rid from this white edging around the border without changing the background color of the page itself?

Sandbox demo: https://jsbin.com/cajobunecu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Try setting border: solid; before the border-top setting.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying yo accomplish here, are you trying to get rid of the white border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to make you sure, `<hr>` includes its border on all 4 sides by default and it's white.

What's happening here is, you're designing only the top border and hence, the remaining 3 borders are in their default condition i.e. white.

The solution is simple, do this.

```
.line {
            border: none;
            border-top: 30px solid #2274ca; 
        }
```